# Stochastic order

Tags: stochastic-processes

I need help with the following exercise:

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables in $\mathbb{R}$ with the distribution functions $F_X$ and $F_Y$, so $X$ is stochastically smaller or equal to $Y$, i.e. $(X\leq_{st}Y)$ if $F_X(t)\geq F_Y(t)$ holds for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

How can I show the following statement?

$X\leq_{st}Y$ implies $E[f(X)]\leq E[f(Y)]$ for every monotone increasing function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so that the given expected values exist.

Comment: You can try approximating $f$ by a class of simple functions (linear combinations of indicator functions). See the first few pages of Shaked and Shanthikumar. Alternatively, if you can show that $X \le_{st} Y$ implies that $E[X] \le E[Y]$, you might also be to show that your assumptions imply that $f(X) \le_{st} f(Y)$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Phi_{X}$ and $\Phi_{Y}$ be functions $\left(0,1\right)\to\mathbb{R}$
prescribed by $u\mapsto\inf\left\{ z\in\mathbb{R}\mid F_{X}\left(z\right)\geq u\right\} $
and $u\mapsto\inf\left\{ z\in\mathbb{R}\mid F_{Y}\left(z\right)\geq u\right\} $
respectively.

These are the so-called "inverses" of $F_X$ and $F_Y$ and it is well known that $\phi_{X}\left(U\right)\stackrel{d}{=}X$ and $\phi_{Y}\left(U\right)\stackrel{d}{=}Y$ if $U$ has uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

Eventually have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3560904/75923) about that fact.

Further $X\leq_{st}Y$ implies that $\Phi_{X}\left(u\right)\leq\Phi_{Y}\left(u\right)$
for every $u\in\left(0,1\right)$ and consequently: $$f\left(\Phi_{X}\left(u\right)\right)\leq f\left(\Phi_{Y}\left(u\right)\right)\text{ for every }u\in\left(0,1\right)$$

Then we find:

$$\mathbb{E}f\left(\phi_{X}\left(U\right)\right)=\int_{0}^{1}f\left(\phi_{X}\left(u\right)\right)du\leq\int_{0}^{1}f\left(\phi_{Y}\left(u\right)\right)du=\mathbb{E}f\left(\phi_{Y}\left(U\right)\right)$$

This with $\mathbb Ef(X)=\mathbb{E}f(\phi_{X}(U)$ and $\mathbb Ef(Y)=\mathbb{E}f(\phi_{Y}(U)$ so we are ready.

This all under assumption that the expectations exist of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental result in stochastic dominance. See theorem 1' on page 29 of [Hadar & Russel 1969](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1811090.pdf?casa_token=8UvoBuaq3XQAAAAA:32V80FGy_BurvUMr4B0jSH_7ZYdjhlMZqVB-urssZVI6vBbgF8Q8_CnpnMXEuoVnFQ1d33us9Qb7f6E22Uz_LtGSbZME5Oy-tQiIpvBADF_96Zv3cX1n).

TL;DR: integrate by parts the difference of the expectations $\int f(x) [F'(x)-G'(x)]dx$

Answer (score 0):

The typical argument of the first-order stochastic dominance property is that
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f_x(t) u(t) dt = [(1-F_x(t))u(t)]_{a}^b + \int_{a}^b u'(t) (1-F_x(t))dt
$$
so that
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f_x(t) u(t) dt -\int_{a}^{b} f_y(t) u(t) dt  = \int_{a}^b u'(t) (F_y(t)-F_x(t))dt,
$$
and since $u'(t) \ge 0$ and $F_x(t) \ge F_y(t)$ for all $t$, the right-hand side is non-positive, so $\int_{a}^{b} f_y(t) u(t) dt \ge \int_{a}^{b} f_x(t) u(t) dt$.

I don't think you can use this kind of argument to prove the expectations exist? If $(1-F_x(b))u(b)$ diverges as $b\rightarrow \infty$, so that $u(t)$ is growing faster than $1-F_x(t)$ is tending to zero, the expectation might fail to exist and the calculation on the first line would fail.

If the distributions have compact support or if $f$ is not just continuous but also bounded, you could prove existence, but it wouldn't really follow from the stochastic dominance argument, just standard results like the dominated convergence theorem.